# Which process will be killed by kernel in case of memory over use? child or parent?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, process

let me cover a small background here:

i am launching one ruby script (script_launcher.rb) through PHP using shell_exec function and in that ruby script i am doing this:

```
spawned_process_id = spawn("ruby actual_script.rb > /dev/null" ) 
Process.wait spawned_process_id
```

and after that according to Process::Status Object i am responding in my ruby script.

This is starting three processes on server:
1) Through PHP script for "ruby script_launcher.rb"
2) Through spawn function somethings like "sh -c ruby actual_script.rb > /dev/null"
3) Through "ruby actual_script.rb"

now my question is if my actual_script.rb is eating up a lot of memory in RAM then which of the above process will be killed by kernel.

The actual problem is here Process::Status Object is storing status of spawned_process_id (Process No. 2) but if kernel is killing Process No. 3 then my logic gives success which is absolutely a wrong case.

Any solution or reference would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think linux would kill a process automatically if there was no special configuration.
Mostly it's the process that kills(maybe by not handling an exception) itself when it can't get no more memory from the system.

Comment: No kernel can kill a process in case of excessive memory use...it is calling OOM Killer to do that.